# Жирный шрифт внутри селекта

Tags: html, css

Как сделать жирный шрифт внутри конструкции select для некоторых option?

```
 <select> 
 <option style="font-weight:bold">тадам</option>
 <option>тададам</option> 
 </select>
```

Этот вариант не работает в opera и chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроссбраузерно - написать свой селект со **стилями и прибамбасами** на JS.
См: JQuery UI
Другого метода особо не существует: селект слишком OS зависимый.